# How can I set an input box to clear its default value on focus using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's a fairly standard UI practice, so I figured I'd be able to find a solution very quickly but I've had no luck.

This is the jQuery I would usually write for this functionality:

```
(function($){   
    $.fn.focusClear = function(text) {
        text = text || this[0].defaultValue;
    this.focus(function() {
      if($(this).val() == text) $(this).val('');
    }).blur(function() {
      if( $(this).val() == '') $(this).val(text);
    });
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

How can I achieve the same effect using Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I'm understanding your intending functionality exactly, but you might be able to use [placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) for something like this?

Comment: How did I not know this?? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I needed this too in angular and came up with this:

```
app.directive('input', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var defaultVal = element.val();

        element.bind("focus", function(e) {
            if(element.val() == defaultVal) element.val('');
        })

        element.bind("blur", function(e) {
            if( element.val() == '') element.val(defaultVal);
        });
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs doesn't have a built in listeners for the focus event, but you can write your own.

But first of all, note that all modern browsers support the `placeholder` attribute on input fields, which does what you want to do.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username">
```

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder may be the answer you needed, but just in case you ever need a bit more control over an element, I would suggest looking into directives:

- Docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive
- Youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqmeI5fZcho

In essence, directives give you the ability to give elements behavior. And, if you are looking to do any kind of DOM manipulation, the suggested method is to use this feature of Angular (never do DOM stuff in controllers). Using the `link` function within a directive, you can easily grab the element, its attributes and manipulate the element's scope.

Hope that helps.